# What does memory reusing actual mean?

Tags: c++, struct, new-operator

What does memory reuse mean? For instance, we've created and object.

```
struct A { };
A *a = new A;
void *p = operator new(sizeof(A),a); //Is it memory reusing?
void *p = realloc(sizeof(A),a); //Is it memory reusing?
```

I ask that question because the example from the section 3.8/6 confuses me. The example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct B {
    virtual void f();
    void mutate();
    virtual ~B();
};
struct D1 : B { void f(); };
struct D2 : B { void f(); };
void B::mutate() {
    new (this) D2; //1, reuses storage — ends the lifetime of *this
    f(); // undefined behavior
    ... = this; // OK, this points to valid memory
}
```

That is, at `//1` we first call `placement-new` which reuses memory, and just after this we construct a new object. Right?

Comment: Why is it Undefined Behaviour?

Comment: @david.pfx: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117358/is-it-allowed-to-write-an-instance-of-derived-over-an-instance-of-base

Comment: The placement form of the allocation function is *always* a no-op.  (The library version is, and the Standard makes your whole program undefined behavior if you supplant the library version, see section `[new.delete.placement]`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, I don't think that's it. I think it must be S3.8/5 `the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object`.

Comment: @david.pfx: My two comments above are completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: @david.pfx: The undefined behavior there comes because that rule DOES apply, and 3.8/7 does not.

Comment: @BenVoigt (1) Yes, I realised (2) I think we are in furious agreement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage reuse happens when any write to any memory occupied by the object takes place, and that write is not performed via a layout-compatible type (basically strict aliasing, but you'd better not use the exception for character types to overwrite parts of an object that isn't trivially copyable).

Using placement new to construct a new object is one example, but another example is using `memcpy` to copy another object on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

Here, storage reuse simply means that the new object is constructed at the address pointed to by `this`, wherever that might be. In other words, no new memory is allocated for the object.

`realloc()` is not a memory reuse tool since it can lead to a new block being allocated. Furthermore, your example has undefined behaviour, since you can't use `realloc()` on memory allocated using `new`.